# transaction.executeSql Success function error

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I did a function that select the data from db and show an alert, but I'm getting the following error in the Success function:

> Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined retrieveData

Here is my functions

```
 function selectAll(){
    DB.transaction(
function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CDprodutos", [], retrieveData()); //The retrieveData function is where the data is sent/returned to in parameters (transation, results)
});
}
function retrieveData(transaction, results) {
   for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

        var data = results.rows.item(i)['id']
        alert(data.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `retrieveData()` is being called immediately. Remove the `()` `retrieveData` call inside the `executeSql` statement. Also, you need to pass the parameters to it, so you're probably going to need an anon. function.

Comment: the function is not called when I remove the ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your function is being executed immediately and also there is no data being passed to it, so obviously the `rows` property is coming from `undefined.` By writing `()` after `retrieveData`, you are invoking the function immediately. Remove the `()` to use this as a callback.

It also appears you need to pass data along to it, so an anonymous function would probably do the trick here:

```
function selectAll(){
    DB.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM CDprodutos", [], function() {
                retrieveData(transation, results); //not sure where results comes from? parameter of function??
        });
    });
}

function retrieveData(transaction, results) {
    for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        var data = results.rows.item(i)['id']
        alert(data.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @shadsauhduisad -- Please mark the answer once you are allowed to. Glad to help.